# Using multiple HAVING with multiple WHERE statement PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a psql query where multiple `WHERE` clauses are being used in groupings (with brackets)

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE (location = 'NYC' OR location = 'BK')
  AND (age > 18)
```

Notice that I have 2 conditions together which are grouped using brackets.

Now I'm trying to use the `COUNT` function to get another data from my dataset and I'm currently doing it using the `HAVING` statement. The problem is that it seems that there is no way to use `HAVING` multiple times (in each brackets) and should rather be used only once after the `AND` or do something like this `HAVING` x and y etc.. but this is not what I want.

I need to use `HAVING` in each brackets like this:

```
SELECT customers.id as id 
FROM customers
INNER JOIN friends ON friends.id = customers.id
WHERE (location = 'NYC' OR location = 'BK'
       GROUP BY customers.id
       HAVING COUNT(friends.id) > 2)
  AND (age > 18
       GROUP BY customers.id
       HAVING COUNT(friends.id) > 10);
```

So essentially (customers who live in NYC or BK having 2 friends) AND (customers 18 yos having more that 10 friends)

Comment: It is absolutely crucial to have them separated into groups using brackets :)

Comment: How about splitting the SQL query into 2 parts, and use UNION on both?

Comment: You are missing significant necessary information. Take a few minuets to review [ask]. Specifically, update your question to include table definitions (ddl) and  sample data (or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14)) and the expected results *of that data*. All as text - **no images**.   Also take a look at [Select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html) statement structure. There can be *only 1* `having` clause per select or sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `CASE WHEN` in a `COUNT`.
And use that in the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT customer.id 
FROM customers AS customer
INNER JOIN friends AS friend
  ON friend.id = customer.id
GROUP BY customer.id
HAVING (   
   COUNT(CASE WHEN friend.location IN ('NYC','BK') 
         THEN friend.id END) > 2
   AND
   COUNT(CASE WHEN friend.age > 18 
         THEN friend.id END) > 10
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN friends f ON f.id = c.id
WHERE
    c.location = ('NYC', 'BK') or c.age > 18
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >
    case when min(c.location) in ('NYC', 'BK') then 2
         when min(c.age) > 18 then 10 end
```

When the conditions overlap it's not clear which requirement applies. If you actually want more than the id back use dummy aggregates or look into `count(*) over (partition by.id)`.